# jQuery 1.9.0 List of Deprecated, Removed, and Changed functionality since 1.6.4

Tags: jquery, deprecated

We are currently upgrading jQuery in our application from jQuery 1.6.4 to 1.9.0.

I believe I have gotten the majority of the changes fixed in our application, however, I would like to be able to go from a semi-solid list of functional jQuery changes to be sure.

As of right now, the only two major changes I see are the removal of the `.live` and the `$.browser` features.

There were also some issues that resulted in us upgrading jquery UI to the latest as well.

We have a large application that we finally got the approval to drop support for IE 6 and therefore are trying to bring it closer to the modern age.

I'm not looking for a complete change log for each version, as the change logs include a lot of stuff I don't really care about. Hopefully this will help others in their upgrade process as well.

What I am looking for: *Deprecated functions*, *Removed functions*, *Important functional changes such as the old `attr` and `prop`*

**What are the deprecated, removed functions, and important functional changes since jQuery 1.6.4 to 1.9.2...**

Comment: So what's your question...

Comment: What are the deprecated, removed functions, and important functional changes since jQuery 1.6.4 to 1.9.2...

Comment: [Did you RTFM for jQuery 1.9.0?  You are not interested in the change log, so you want somebody here to read it to you instead?](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/15/jquery-1-9-final-jquery-2-0-beta-migrate-final-released/)  **Just do the work!**

Comment: 1.9.0 just came out. 1.8.2 has been updated to 1.8.3. 1.9.2 does not yet exist. Whatever you're actually upgrading to, the answer will be the same: [read the change logs yourself](http://blog.jquery.com).

Comment: I upvote this question. Although the change log is there, it is scattering all over the places.

Comment: My bad 1.9.2 is jQuery UI. @Sparky - Yup. The point of the question is to point out major changes that might not be caught in the scattered change logs.

Comment: @nhahtdh, you do this community a disservice.  Somebody has to actually _read_ the changelogs... it might as well be the person who needs the information.

Comment: @Sparky: Well, I think it is good to have the information and links in one place, even if this question is later closed.

Comment: [The jQuery Blog](http://blog.jquery.com) gives a summary of the most important information in the changelogs. I hope you're at least reading that.

Comment: @nhahtdh, [they are already in one place!](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: @Sparky: Older links are not available, and has to be accessed via Google. jQueryUI does have a good CHANGELOG page, though.

Comment: @Sparky I see 1.8ish. I'm asking for this from 1.6.4 up. I don't see upgrade guides that go that far back.

Comment: For jQueryUI: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Changelog

Comment: Here you go @Tom, [release notes (with changelogs) all the way back to 1.6.3](http://jquery.com/download/)

Comment: @Sparky: Cool. I notice those change logs include names of the problems, not how they were solved. (IE not necessarily denoting the deprecation or functional changes.)

Comment: Each item is a hyperlink that when clicked leads to a page with further explanation of the problem... or am I looking at something else?

Comment: Nope, and to save other users time, why not make a list here of all significant changes?

Comment: Go ahead, you are free to do all the work and post an answer yourself.  (Then you can define _"significant change"_ however you wish)

Comment: @Tom: I think you can start writing a draft of a self-answer and post it, then edit it later. Otherwise, this question looks like it is going to be closed.

Comment: @nhahtdh Looks like that'll be the best option. While jQuery does have a nice 1.9 upgrade guide, it doesn't answer all the important things breaking in our application as a result of the upgrade. Which is the point of the question - to save users the time of reading all the changelogs and unnecessary comments in their change logs.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since this question may be closed, it makes sense as nhahtdh suggested to submit an answer to be able to edit and add information later. Feel free to make changes to add additional change notes and even increase this to the latest versions of jQuery (1.10)

***>= jQuery 1.6.4***

No significant changes noted

***>= jQuery 1.7.1***

No significant changes noted

***>= jQuery 1.7.2***

From Docs: `If you’re using jQuery Mobile, please use jQuery 1.7.2 only with jQuery Mobile 1.1. For previous versions of jQuery Mobile, stay with jQuery core 1.7.1 or earlier.`

***>= jQuery 1.8.0***

Core changes to watch:

- **`animations`** - core changes
- **`CSS Prefixing`**

  - From jquery:

> When you use a CSS property, in either .css() or .animate(), we’ll use the correct prefixed property (when appropriate) for that browser. For example, take .css("user-select", "none"); in Chrome/Safari we’ll set the value as "-webkit-user-select", Firefox will use "-moz-user-select", and IE10 will use "-ms-user-select".

**`data`**:

> The .data() method had an undocumented and incredibly non-performant way to monitor setting and getting of values that was removed in 1.9. This has affected the interpretation of data names that contain periods, in a good way. As of 1.9, a call to .data("abc.def") retrieves the data for the name "abc.def" only, and never just "abc". Note that the lower-level jQuery.data() method never supported events and so it has not changed. The jQuery Migrate plugin does not restore the old behavior for this case.

**`.curCSS`**: This one is an important one for me. Upgrading the the new jQuery UI fixed this issue, but it is important to note, that without upgrading, this will break various things.

> $.curCSS: This method was simply an alias for jQuery.css() from jQuery 1.3 onward. Although it has never been part of the documented API, some external code has been known to use it, perhaps thinking it was “more efficient.” Now it’s “more gone.”

***>= jQuery 1.8.1***

jQuery notes: `Use jQuery UI 1.8.23 and jQuery Mobile 1.1.1 or later for best compatibility with jQuery core 1.8.1.`

`Don’t use Quirks mode! http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/30/jquery-1-8-1-released/`

***>= jQuery 1.8.2***

- offset: This could effect a page that was expecting a value from offset to be off already in a specific browser. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12536

> MAKE .OFFSET() CALC LESS WRONG ON BROWSERS W/O GETBOUNDINGCLIENTRECT

***>= jQuery 1.8.3***

No significant changes noted

***>= jQuery 1.9.0*** from http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

- `.toggle(function, function, ... ) removed`

  > This is the "click an element to run the specified functions" signature of .toggle(). It should not be confused with the "change the visibility of an element" of .toggle() which is not deprecated.
- `jQuery.browser() removed`
- `.live() removed`
- `.die() removed`
- `jQuery.sub() removed`
- `.add()` changes http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#add-
- `.addBack( selector ) replaces .andSelf()` http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#addback-selector-replaces-andself-
- `.after(), .before(), and .replaceWith() with disconnected nodes`
- `.appendTo, .insertBefore, .insertAfter, and .replaceAll`
- `AJAX events should be attached to document`
- `Checkbox/radio state in a .trigger()ed "click" event`
- `Order of triggered "focus" events`
- `jQuery(htmlString) versus jQuery(selectorString)`
- `Events not fired by the .data() method; names with periods`
- `Ordering of disconnected nodes within a jQuery set`
- `Loading and running scripts inside HTML content`
- `.attr() versus .prop()`
- `$("input").attr("type", newValue) in oldIE`
- `"hover" pseudo-event`
- `.selector property on jQuery objects`
- `jQuery.attr()`
- `jQuery.ajax returning a JSON result of an empty string`
- `jQuery.proxy() context`
- `.data("events")`
- `Removed properties of the Event object`
- `Undocumented arguments of API methods`

I will review and add to this later as I find more issues.

Comment: in 1.7 something they removed .live()

Comment: @cubsink, it was deprecated in 1.7, and removed in 1.9, per http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed

Answer (score 2):

Latest jQuery release is 1.9.0 and this is the upgrade-guide doc

http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

You can find these here:

### Changes of Note in jQuery 1.9

- `.toggle(function, function, ... )` removed
- `jQuery.browser()` removed
- `.live()` removed
- `.die()` removed
- `jQuery.sub()` removed
- `.add()`
- `.addBack( selector )` replaces `.andSelf()`
- `.after()`, `.before()`, and `.replaceWith() with disconnected nodes`
- `.appendTo`, `.insertBefore`, `.insertAfter`, and `.replaceAll`
- AJAX events should be attached to document
- Checkbox/radio state in a `.trigger()`ed `"click"` event
- Order of triggered `"focus"` events
- `jQuery(htmlString)` versus `jQuery(selectorString)`
- Events not fired by the `.data()` method; names with periods
- Ordering of disconnected nodes within a jQuery set
- Loading and running scripts inside HTML content
- `.attr()` versus `.prop()`
- `$("input").attr("type", newValue)` in oldIE
- `"hover"` pseudo-event
- .selector property on jQuery objects
- `jQuery.attr()`
- `jQuery.ajax` returning a JSON result of an empty string
- `jQuery.proxy()` context
- `.data("events")`
- Removed properties of the Event object
- Undocumented arguments of API methods
- Other undocumented properties and methods

Comment: This is a nice summary of 1.9, but it doesn't really answer the OP's question.  He wants "all significant changes" since version 1.6.4.